# Does the header would be included explicitly when use find_package in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

When I use PyTorch for C++, it's pretty easy to just use find_package to set up the dependency. And here is the `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0 FATAL_ERROR)
project(dcgan)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /User/root/libtorch) # I added this line, does it effect?
find_package(Torch REQUIRED)

add_executable(dcgan dcgan.cpp)
target_link_libraries(dcgan "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")
set_property(TARGET dcgan PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)
```

There isn't any explicit command to include the header, but the header could be found if `target_link_libraries(dcgan "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")` exists. I am curious why the header file could be found even there is no `target_include_directories(dcgan PUBLIC ${TORCH_INCLUDE_DIRS})`.

The code is on the official website of PyTorch and it works on MacOS and Linux. What happened.

ADD:
The package is in a directory where the compiler knows nothing about it.

Comment: Perhaps the package has been installed in a default location, where the compiler already looks for header files?

Comment: You also can say `find_package` where to search for the package explicitly either while calling configuration step via `-DTORCH_DIR` or looking here https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#search-procedure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The include path can be set as propagated setting in the dependency:

> **target_link_libraries**
>
> Specify libraries or flags to use when linking a given target and/or
> its dependents. Usage requirements from linked library targets will be
> propagated. Usage requirements of a target’s dependencies affect
> compilation of its own sources.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html

That means that `target_link_libraries` will configure the target . It will set `target_compile_features`, `target_compile_options`, `target_compile_directories`, if they're set as `INTERFACE` or `PUBLIC` in the dependency.

E.g.

```
add_library(Lib ${SRCS_LIB})
target_include_directories(Lib INTERFACE ${DIRECTORY})

add_exectuable(Exe ${SRCS_EXE})
target_link_libraries(Exe PRIVATE Lib)
```

In this example `Exe` will inherit the include directories from `Lib`. You don't need to set them explicitly.

That's also how [Conan](https://conan.io/) works, e.g. [Getting started](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
 project(MD5Encrypter)

 add_definitions("-std=c++11")

 include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
 conan_basic_setup()

 add_executable(md5 md5.cpp)
 target_link_libraries(md5 ${CONAN_LIBS})
```

and how it's described in [Effective Modern CMake](https://gist.github.com/mbinna/c61dbb39bca0e4fb7d1f73b0d66a4fd1)

> **Use exported targets of external packages.**
>
> Don’t fall back to the old
> CMake style of using variables defined by external packages. Use the
> exported targets via `target_link_libraries` instead.

Best practice is to not use `target_include_directories` for your dependencies.

Comment: Yeah I found `set_target_properties(torch PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "${TORCH_LIBRARY}"
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${TORCH_INCLUDE_DIRS}"
    CXX_STANDARD 14
)`  in the `TorchConfig.cmake` and it does include the header in the target torch which is linked later.